# Ansible apply tags from a playbook (not command line)

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I run my playbook `a.yaml`, and in `a.yaml` I want to include one or more tasks from `b.yaml`.
First, I tried put following on `a.yaml`:

```
import_playbook: b.yaml --tags "tag1"
```

But this errors out saying the `--tags` doesn't apply to import_playbook.
Based on latest Ansible `include_tasks` documentation, I tried with following:
`a.yaml`:

```
- include_tasks:
    file: b.yaml
    apply:
      tags: tag1
```

`b.yaml`:

```
- shell: echo $HOSTNAME
  register: hostname
  tags: tag1

- debug:
    msg: "task2"
  tags: tag2
```

But both tasks in `b.yaml` got invoked though I only expected the first as tag indicated.

**Questions:**

- How to have tags passed from `a.yaml` to `b.yaml` and get recognized? I don't mind to use something else if include_tasks is not the solution.
- How to pass the result (the hostname, or any result) from `b.yaml` back to caller `a.yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is - sadly - not possible.
Tags that are to be executed can only be specified on the cli.

`apply` does not specify which tags to include, but applies the tag to each task in the included file. That means that it adds the tag, the same way as if you added `tags: tag1` to all your tasks in `b.yaml`.

If you want to only include certain tasks of a file, they need to have that tag in that file, and then you can use `--tags "tag1"` on the cli.
I would advise you not to do that excessively, as it will get very hard to find out what is actually going to happen for anybody who reads the code later, including you.

Meta: *Please only ask one question per post on Stackoverflow.*

I do not get your second question. If you include tasks from a different file, they are executed the same way as if they were directly there, so you do not need to pass anything. You can just access it.

E.g. like this:

`main.yml`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks:
        file: i.yml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ tvar.stdout }}"
```

`i.yml`:

```
- shell: date -u
  register: tvar
```

Result:

```
TASK [include_tasks] **********************************************************************************
included: /home/.../test/i.yml for localhost

TASK [shell] **********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ons 14 apr 2021 05:34:25 UTC"
}
```

Comment: Hi @toydarian, thanks for response. in my case. a.yaml is the normal playbook, I try to make b.yaml a common lib-like task file shared by playbooks like a.yaml. So directly calling b.yaml with tags is not an option since it's part of the flow in a.yaml, and I don't want to add a Linux shell layer on top. The second question was just in case I got an answer other than include_task. Regards!

Comment: If you want to make a "lib", do NOT rely on tags to include parts of it. I've tried that, it is utter madness and will give you tons of headache. Make one file for each part, and always include a whole file. If you find out you need to include part of it, break that part out into another file.

Comment: Advice taken. Will do. Thanks!

Comment: If you really want to include part of a file, use conditionals with `when`. That works ok-ish.

Comment: I'll keep this option in mind, see if I can fit it in. Otherwise I'll split. Thanks